# Azure SDK - Copy Azure SQL database Schema only through code

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-sql-database, schema

Currently use the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent libraries in our solution to create copies of Azure SQL databases - works well:

```
await server.Databases.Define(databaseName).WithExistingElasticPool(elasticPoolName).WithSourceDatabase(source).WithMode(CreateMode.Copy).CreateAsync();
```

Is there a way to do the same thing but only copy the schema - no data rows?

I was hoping for a WithMode option but nothing stands out in the documentation.

Thanks much in advance

Comment: Is this helpful: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1574.overview-of-options-for-migrating-data-and-schema-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx? Which type of code do you want use?

Comment: Thanks for the response!   Currently when creating a new blank database we have the C# code referenced above in the original question.  That creates a blank database.  We then have to apply the schema to it running a script one line at a time.  With our large complex database that can take a long time.   If there isn't a way to do this we will have to construct and maintain a blank database that has the schema and no records then copy from there.  Definitely doable - but was hoping to be able to skip that.   Thanks again!!